# What does SignedCms.decode() do in c#

Tags: c#, c++, openssl, pkcs#7

I want to implement SignedCms.decode() function in c++ but I don't know what does it do like code? all I know is that SignedCms.encode() generate BER encoded bytes and I am not even sure about that.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation about the SignedCms class and the Decode method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.decode?view=netframework-4.7.2) and if you want to look at the source and what exactly it does you can use one of many C# decompilers like the JetBrains [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or the Telerik [JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I read the documentation but couldn't find what encoding is used so I wanted to look at the code to understand thanks for the links.

Comment: Since you’re asking sort of high level, SignedCms is a representation of signed data from https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652. Decode reads in an existing BER encoded signed data payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend that you implement your own SignedCms.decode since that would involve implementing an ASN.1 reader which is a complex task.

If you are on Windows OS, i would recommend taking a look at this: [CryptMsgOpenToDecode function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptmsgopentodecode)

Comment: Thanks the problem is that the code intended to be cross platform , doesn't openssl library provide an ASN.1 reader ?

Comment: Yes openssl does include an ASN1 parser. However, even after parsing the ASN1 you need to extract SignedCms information from the ASN1 which i don't know if openssl supports.